# Build secure private ethereum blockchain with geth!

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, security, peers

I have read on the StackExchange how to build a private blockchain in LAN with private IPs and geth clients.

As I understood to communicate in lan the geth peers need for P2P communication the form of "enode://pubkey@ip:port"
But still they are using the por 30303 and JSON-HTTP or JSON-RPC. But can this communication be made more secure and also the interraction with the WebBrowsers (MetaMask) and communication between peers like with https. 
Because I see this as an Security Issue when Geth client so communicates. I can make the peers fix but it is also a Problem.

Do you have some proposals to this topic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The protocol is encrypted https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md.

Comment: Thanks. The P2P Traffic is encrypted. RLPx. What about API Interaction over JSON-RPC. This is still HTTP?

Comment: By default RPC port 8545 and websocket 8546 are not open, and if they are open you have no authentication they will listen to any command from anyone connected. If you decide to open them you should put at least a https in front (I've used nginx for that), and depending on your use case some authentication.